# Apparent compile bug in VisualStudio Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506.0

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have written a minimum case for this bug, and it generates the EXTRN statement:
    EXTRN   _.?AU_anc@8:PROC

Here is the code - can someone spot what I am doing wrong.  When I have three statements starting with THRCOMP, and 3 corresponding proc_ent statements, it compiles the first and the last OK, and the 2nd one generating the above bug.

```
struct  _anchor
{
    int(*svc_addr) (int, void * vptr, ...);

void *reserved;
};

typedef  _anchor anchor;

#define THRCOMP extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall

struct _proc_ent {
_proc_ent *succ;
char proc_name[32];
char comp_name[200];
int (__stdcall *faddr) (_anchor anch);
void *proc_block;   // used as a temporary placeholder by thxbnet
void * label_ptr;   // points to a label for subnets     
bool trace;
bool composite;
bool must_run;  
};

typedef  _proc_ent proc_ent;

#define TRACE true
#define COMPOS true
#define NULL 0

THRCOMP ThFileWt(_anchor anch);
THRCOMP ThCopyNL(_anchor anch);
THRCOMP ThFileRd(_anchor anch);

proc_ent P0 = { NULL, "Read", "ThFileRd", ThFileRd, NULL, NULL, 
    TRACE, !COMPOS };
proc_ent P1 = { &P0, "Show", "ThFileWt", ThFileWt, NULL, NULL,
    TRACE, !COMPOS };
proc_ent P2 = { &P1, "Copy", "ThCopyNL", ThCopyNL, NULL, NULL, 
    TRACE, !COMPOS };
```

If anyone can shed light on this, or give me a workaround, it would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have code defined anywhere for `ThFileRd()` et al?

With the code as written I got undefined symbols for p0, p1 etc, which appear to correspond to the function names for all except the last one:

```
1>Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ThFileRd@8
1>Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _.?AU_anc@8
1>Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ThFileWt@8
1>Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ThCopyNL@8
```

Got this when I added `proc_ent P3 = { &P2, "Wibble", "ThWibble", ThWibble, NULL, NULL, TRACE, !COMPOS };` and the corresponding THRCOMP definition.

This is pretty much what I'd expect to see as there is no code for those functions; what was unexpected though was the change in name for the last function (apparently from `ThWibble` to `.?AU_anc`).

Rearranging the order of the THRCOMP definitions made no difference.

If I comment out p3 and p2 then the name change moves to p1:

```
1>Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ThFileRd@8
1>Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _.?AU_anc@8
```

But if I change the definitions to include a function body, for example `THRCOMP ThWibble(_anchor anch) {return 0;}`, the code compiles without any errors.  I'm using VS2015 Community, and pasted the code into a Win32 DLL project.

I've no idea though where `_.?AU_anc@8` comes from, and why this value should only correspond to the last pN definition.  I'd have thought if there was something wrong with the p2 definition then the error would remain regardless of whether or not p3 is defined, and similarly that if there was nothing wrong with the p1 definition that it wouldn't suddenly acquire something wrong when p2 is commented out.

Comment: Dave, sorry I didn't get this in my email, so I just saw it.  Thanks for looking into it for me.  Still a mystery: if I change the stdcalls to cdecls the problem goes away, and I get clean link!  However, using stdcall, I don't see why the source for ThFileRd, etc. needs to be in the same compilable as the mainline that calls them - we never had to do that in the past.  I suppose I could #include all the subroutines in the mainline, but I like having separate compilables!  Seems like a bona fide compiler bug, n'est-ce pas?